# is there a way to password protect the www folder?

Tags: php, apache, web, directory

I am programming intranet applications, but the server is used as workstation too. I would like to know if there is a way to restrict access to WWW folder in order to hide the server code (PHP in this case) from the people who use these apps.

With this I would also protect the password of the database which is written in a script inside the WWW folder.

I have been looking around for a while but I haven't been able to find anything about this.

I talked to a fiend of mine, he told me that if I used windows I could create a user in windows and make the folder only accessible by this account and grant Apache access to it as well in this case we could see the website from any of the other user accounts but there won't be access to the files.

I worried about the possibility of somebody using a live CD of any linux distro to get the files and he told me that if I installed grub and lock it it wont be possible to use a live cd for that unless the person who does it has the grub key.

of course the same would be possible in linux. 
Can anyone explain the process?
Any other suggestion?

Comment: You are saying there is no permissions system in place on Windows?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? You're selling a web-based product (for example, an intranet) and install that in-house at a clients computer, but don't want the client to have access to your source-code (php) and database?

Comment: yes I mean I am selling web aplications for intranet services and I dont want them to have access to the source  code.

Comment: @PeeHaa there is a permission system on windows but I have passed it using a simple live cd of ubuntu. I can access all of the files on disk and do whatever I want no matter what windows permissions I have on them.

Comment: If you don't want people to access your code don't share it. period.

Comment: Windows permissions don't apply to Linux. In fact, you can use an Ubuntu live CD and view all the files on a hard drive that has Linux installed on it too. Perhaps you should explain in more detail exactly what you're trying to accomplish and why. Either way, this doesn't belong on StackOverflow. I'm voting to have this moved to serverfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very easy to do on Linux. Say, for example, you have the website owner's user called `john` and you have another user on the system called `bob`. You don't want `bob` to be able to see `john`'s files, but you want them to be accessible to Apache. Apache runs by default as a separate user (usually `apache` or `www-data`) and is a member of both the `john` and `bob` groups.

The directory that holds the files should then have to have no permissions for "other", at least read and execute permissions for "group" and probably full access to the user.

```
drwxr-x--- 35 john john 4096 Jan 29 15:47 /path/to/john/webroot/
```

You can do this by executing the following:

```
chmod 750 /path/to/john/webroot/
```

The files, in order to be accessible by Apache, will only need read access. You can then chmod them 640:

```
chmod 640 /path/to/john/webroot/super_sensitive_config_file.php
```

Which should then show you something like this:

```
$ ls -l super_sensitive_config_file.php
-rw-r----- 1 john john 385 Jan 19 16:27 super_sensitive_config_file.php
```

The `bob` user should then see something like this:

```
bob@server:~$ cat /path/to/john/webroot/super_sensitive_config_file.php
cat: /path/to/john/webroot/super_sensitive_config_file.php: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

All non-web related assets (e.g. not html files, css, javascript, etc) should be placed outside of the document root. That way they cannot be accessed through a browser.

Comment: this reads as if you are saying html, css, javascript should be placed outside of the document root. I'm assuming you are meaning everything except those should be outside.

Comment: I think the OP means that a person *physically* working on the server (using it as a workstation) should not be allowed to access the files of the website.

Comment: @thaJeztah that is exactly what I mean the app should be accessed  via localhost or the ip but not the source itself and by that I mean server side code which also contains config files and the password to access the database.

Answer (score 0):

Completely blocking access to the files will probably not be possible, because the owner of the computer (your client) probably has administrator-permissions, so is always able to override whatever restrictions you're putting on the files/folders.

That leaves you with a few other options

1. Don't install on the computer of the client, but sell a 'whole' package, including a small server that only you can administer
2. Run the website on a Virtual Machine that is installed on the clients computer (e.g. VMWare, Parallels Desktop or something alike). Only you are allowed full access to the virtual machine, so the same applies as option 1
3. 'Obfuscate' the PHP source. There are some options for this (search for PHP obfuscate), but I would advice option 1 or 2

Of course, you could always offer the website as a 'hosted' service, running on a external web server, although it will be important to have all the right security in place if important information and private information is contained.